# exit/break main function from called/child function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create something like button loading  in bootstrap. basically creating a loading text inside a button/link and preventing button/link from functioning until the end of operation

So here is my prototype

```
function btnLoader(b){
    var txt = b.attr('data-text' , b.text());
    b.addClass('disabled').text('......');
}

function btnunLoader(b){
    b.removeClass('disabled').text( b.attr('data-text'));
}
```

So this works fine like

```
<a href="#" onclick="mainFunction(1);" id="btn-1"> send comment </a>
<script>
function mainFunction( id){
    btnLoader($('#btn-'+id));
    do stuff 
    btnunLoader($('#btn-'+id));
}
</script>
```

or

```
<a href="#" id="like-btn"> LIKE </a>
<script>
$('#like-btn').on('click'  , function(){
    btnLoader($(this));
    do stuff        
})
</script>
```

Here is the problem:
I want the button to be disabled after the loading

I can do something like this to check if button already has `disabled` class

```
function btnLoader(b){

    if(b.hasClass('disabled'))
        return false;

    var txt = b.attr('data-text' , b.text());
    b.addClass('disabled').text('......');
}
```

But it has no effect on the `mainFunction` which is calling the `btnLoader` function or on the second example i want to break the click event from `btnLoader`

Is there anyway to do that ?

**Pleas note that clicked element might be `<a>` or any other tag and they don't have a disabled attribute so that's not an option**

Comment: why do you want to break the main function?? everything looks fine in your code. What is not happening as you desire?

Comment: @Reddy lets say its a button to send comments , in the main function   i want to send a ajax request and save the comment in database ... right now user can save a comment multiple times by repeatedly clicking the button but if i break the main function after the first click it wont happen

Comment: unbind the click event on the first time of button click, Then when the process is complete you can bind the click event back. It would be simple code without much headache

Comment: If you can provide the HTML being used and how the click events are binded, I can help you out with a solution.

Comment: @Reddy i want a global solution that covers all scenarios , i've updated my answer with html code and different scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a callback to me. I suppose a `jQuery` function will be ok.

```js
$.fn.btnLoader = function(callback) {
  this.on('click', function() {
    btnLoader.call(this, callback);
  });
};

function btnLoader(callback) {


  if ($(this).is('.disabled'))
    return;
  
  console.log("doing btnLoader stuff");
  var txt = $(this).attr('data-text', $(this).text());
  $(this).addClass('disabled').text('......');
  callback.call($(this));
}


function mainFunction() {

  console.log("doing stuff");
  // do stuff
  btnunLoader(this);
}


$('#like-btn').btnLoader(function() {
  console.log("doing other stuff");
  // do stuff 
});

function btnunLoader() {
  $(this).removeClass('disabled').text($(this).attr('data-text'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="btnunLoader.call(this,mainFunction)" id="btn-1"> send comment </a>
<br>
<a href="#" id="like-btn"> LIKE </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) => `if(b.prop('disabled', true))`

*Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more properties for every matched element.*

Comment: thanx i know how disable a button , but the clicked element might be a `<a>` or any other tag  so there is no disabled property  there .....

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a variable that will set a flag stating if the button is currently loading. And then remove the flag on button unload function. So in this mean time if at all there are other calls to `btnLoader()` function it wont process it until the flag is set back to false. Here is a code to make you understand better.

```
var btnBusy = false;

function btnLoader(b){
  if(!btnBusy ){ // if button is not busy, ie if its not in a loading state, then put to loading state.
    var txt = b.attr('data-text' , b.text());
    b.addClass('disabled').text('......');
  }
 // else since the button is busy just don't do anything on consecutive calls to this function
}

function btnunLoader(b){
  if(btnBusy ){
     b.removeClass('disabled').text( b.attr('data-text'));
     btnBusy = false;  // set back the busy status to false
   }
}
```

**EDIT :** If breaking the main function which called the child function is your only goal. Then you can do the below stuff.

```
function mainFunction( id){
   var loaderStatus = btnLoader($('#btn-'+id));
   if ( loaderStatus === 'break') {
      return;  // this will break your main function
   }
    do stuff 
    btnunLoader($('#btn-'+id));
}
```

And you can have your logic in the `btnLoader` function to when ever it should break the main function and return a `break` string back to main function.

```
function btnLoader(b){
    // to break the function which called this function
    return 'break';
    .....
    .....
}
```

Comment: thanx but it has no effect on main function which the whole point  , also it will break all button/links in the page .. i want to disable already clicked button not all buttons together

Comment: `also it will break all button/links in the page .. i want to disable already clicked button not all buttons together ` You dint even mention you had multiple buttons in your page in the first place. And If breaking your main function is the only goal of yours, then take a look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something simplistic like the following? Simply have the btnLoader return false if it should not proceed and true if it should proceed?

```
function mainFunction( id){
    if(btnLoader($('#btn-'+id)) === false) {
        return;
    }
    //do stuff 
    btnunLoader($('#btn-'+id));
}

function btnLoader(b){

    if(b.hasClass('disabled'))
        return false;

    var txt = b.attr('data-text' , b.text());
    b.addClass('disabled').text('......');
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you do not want to modify the main function for some unknown reason then you could always throw an error (although this would probably be looked down upon by a lot of people).

```
function btnLoader(b){
    if(b.hasClass('disabled'))
        throw "disabled";
    var txt = b.attr('data-text' , b.text());
    b.addClass('disabled').text('......');
}
```

Comment: i know i might sound picky , but for something that i will use hundreds of times in my codes i need  it to be as simple as possible ... so even a simple `if (!) ->  return false ` is too much code ... something like this will be my plan b

Comment: @max I changed my answer. It would do what you want but I wouldn't recommend doing it that way.